Fixing distorted part of the signal for signal preprocessing?
i'm trying to replace the distorted part of my signal wich is a multiplicative season + linear trend kind of signal , i tryed replacing it with the mean or median value but it's not what i want really , i want to restore the original form of the signal , could i use monte carlo simulation to simulate it ?
HELP

Hi and welcome. In order for us to  help you, you need to add a lot more detail. Best would be to show the data as it currently is, the data as you want it to look like and any information of what exactly happened to it.
